# How to install WinFF

Tags: software-installation, winff

I'm having problems installing WinFF. I can't use the Software center, searching for WinFF gives me 'No Application Found'.

So I installed it manually:

```
sudo apt-get
sudo apt-get install winff
```

That works, but I'm stuck with 2 problems. No. 1 is this error message:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion 'GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed
```

And no. 2 is I can only start WinFF from the command line:

```
sudo /usr/bin/winff
```

How can I fix the error and get WinFF to work from Unity?

Comment: which ubuntu version you'r using

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're running winff using `sudo`? What happens if you just run `winff` on the command line? Same error message?

Comment: None, I started it because that was used in the tutorial I found online. Having read your comment, I found I can do it without sudo.
The error message remains the same.

Comment: @Jos The GTK warning is harmless; don't worry about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm your issue with WinFF *not appearing* in the Ubuntu Software Center, my testing done on Xenial Xerus 16.04 LTS. Best advice here is to do as you have already done and install from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install winff libavcodec-extra
```

(Note the addition of the `libavcodec-extra` package, necessary for many of WinFF's encoding command lines.) But for future installations have a look at Synaptic which still works flawlessly on all of my Ubuntu installations:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

The screenshot below demonstrates that unlike the Software Center Synaptic clearly displays WinFF:

[image]

WinFF will not appear in Dash immediately after installation and even opening and closing Dash before trying again will have no effect. However if you log out and then log back in you will see the following:

[image]

**Notes:**

- The GTK error message seen on the command line can be safely ignored, I see this as well on my own system when running WinFF from the command line. It is a *spurious* warning that you will not see when you safely run the application from Dash...

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I followed your instructions and WinFF is running. But with a problem. When I want to work with it I get this error message:
    

    Unable to create file "/home/jos/.winff/ff160923161218.sh".

Press OK to ignore and risk data corruption.
Press Cancel to kill the program.

Comment: I can't get beyond that, the only option is to close the program. Anything else doesn't work.

Comment: @Jos This looks like it could be another question but try the following anyway: 1. Close WinFF 2. Run `mv -v /home/jos/.winff/ /home/jos/.winff_bak` 3. Reopen WinFF. WinFF will recreate the directory and hopefully all will be well. Otherwise you may have a permission issue which goes beyond the scope of your current question.

Comment: That's what I was missing. This works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: After installation you can see WinFF in Dash without logging out, just press keys Alt+F2, type `winff` and you will see `winff` with '3 gears' basic icon.